# Qt list.clear() does it destroy the object's?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qlist

Let's say I have the following list:

```
QList<Type*> list;
list.add(new Type());
list.add(new Type());
list.add(new Type());
list.add(new Type());
list.add(new Type());
list.add(new Type());
```

If I want to empty the list, I can call `list.clear()`

Does it then automatically delete every pointer or do I have to do the following to prevent memory leaks:

```
foreach (Type* t, list) delete t;
list.clear();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it just removes them from the list. You have to delete it on your own. Here can you find the implementation to make sure:

```
template <typename T>
Q_OUTOFLINE_TEMPLATE void QList<T>::clear()
{
    *this = QList<T>();
}
```

and here is the documentation saying that it only removes them from the list, but it is not deleting:

> [void QList::clear()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlist.html#clear)
>
> Removes all items from the list.

If you want to delete them, I suggest to use the following algorithm:

> [void qDeleteAll(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html#qDeleteAll)
>
> Deletes all the items in the range [begin, end) using the C++ delete operator. The item type must be a pointer type (for example, QWidget *).
>
> Example:

```
QList<Employee *> list;
list.append(new Employee("Blackpool", "Stephen"));
list.append(new Employee("Twist", "Oliver"));

qDeleteAll(list.begin(), list.end());
list.clear();
```

Comment: So it's just those 2 lines?

Comment: @Niklas: no, please use qDeleteAll.

Answer (score 3):

if you want them destroyed automatically then you need to either delete them manually or store a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr<Type>`, `QPointer<Type>` (if `Type` is a QObject), ...) in the list